# How to make specific CultureInfo from neutral one and a region code?

Tags: c#

Say I have this:

```
var ci = new CultureInfo("en");
```

and the ISO region-code `"GB"`.

How do I achieve the below (an `en-GB` `CultureInfo` instance), without doing the string concatenation (because that doesn't work for all culture-codes)

```
var ci2 = new CultureInfo(ci.Name + "-" + "GB");
```

Is there some real equivalent of this pseudo code:

```
var ci2 = ci.ToSpecific("GB")
```

Comment: ci2.CreateSpecificCulture will do roughly what you're describing - but your question cites only one specific example (en-GB), without explaining why you're trying to do this or why you think it will fail. Where are the combinations of neutral cultures and specific culture codes coming from? Are you aware that there are some specific cultures that don't use an ISO country code, such as en-029 for Caribbean English?